# Pandas dataframe columns extension using another dataframe column values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes (df1 and df2) as follows:

```
In [4]:df1
   Year  Annual Counts
0  1979          45345
1  1980          15381
2  1981          32171
3  1982          30288
4  1983          50573
In [5]:df2
   Year  CanESM2  GFDL-ESM2M  HadGEM2-ES365  IPSL-CM5A-MR  NorESM1-M
0  1984    10645       48143          57366         26979      37603
1  1985    15918       17178          34617         21304      31956
2  1986    51790       44111          50017         29233      61203
3  1987    34039       14504          23136         35848      34688
4  1988    68641       67681          24322         39591      34553
```

and I would like to combine both dataframes as follows:

```
   Year  CanESM2  GFDL-ESM2M  HadGEM2-ES365  IPSL-CM5A-MR  NorESM1-M
0  1979    45345       45345          45345         45345      45345
1  1980    15381       15381          15381         15381      15381
2  1981    32171       32171          32171         32171      32171
3  1982    30288       30288          30288         30288      30288
4  1983    50573       50573          50573         50573      50573 
5  1984    10645       48143          57366         26979      37603
6  1985    15918       17178          34617         21304      31956
7  1986    51790       44111          50017         29233      61203
8  1987    34039       14504          23136         35848      34688
9  1988    68641       67681          24322         39591      34553
```

One simple solution I have:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(file1)
df1_list = df1['Annual Counts'].tolist()
# empty lists
ext1=[] ; ext2=[] ; ext3=[] ; ext4=[] ; ext5=[]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(file2)
models = ['CanESM2','GFDL-ESM2M','HadGEM2-ES365','IPSL-CM5A-MR','NorESM1-M']
for idx,m in enumerate(models):
    ext+str(idx).append(df1_list)
    df2_mod = df2[m].tolist()
    ext+str(idx).extend(df2_mod)
```

Any suggestions if pandas have any function to perform this task without the need to create multiple lists and then extending them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:
Rename the column `Annual Counts` to `CanESM2` and then use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) after setting `Year` and `CanESM2` as index, finally [`ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) on `axis=1`

```
(df1.rename(columns={'Annual Counts':'CanESM2'})
.set_index(['Year','CanESM2']).combine_first(df2.set_index(['Year','CanESM2']))
.reset_index().ffill(axis=1))
```

---

Another way using [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
(df1.rename(columns={'Annual Counts':'CanESM2'})
   .merge(df2,how='outer',on=['Year','CanESM2']).ffill(axis=1))
```

---

```
     Year  CanESM2  GFDL-ESM2M  HadGEM2-ES365  IPSL-CM5A-MR  NorESM1-M
0  1979.0  45345.0     45345.0        45345.0       45345.0    45345.0
1  1980.0  15381.0     15381.0        15381.0       15381.0    15381.0
2  1981.0  32171.0     32171.0        32171.0       32171.0    32171.0
3  1982.0  30288.0     30288.0        30288.0       30288.0    30288.0
4  1983.0  50573.0     50573.0        50573.0       50573.0    50573.0
5  1984.0  10645.0     48143.0        57366.0       26979.0    37603.0
6  1985.0  15918.0     17178.0        34617.0       21304.0    31956.0
7  1986.0  51790.0     44111.0        50017.0       29233.0    61203.0
8  1987.0  34039.0     14504.0        23136.0       35848.0    34688.0
9  1988.0  68641.0     67681.0        24322.0       39591.0    34553.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Same way as anky_91 answer with renaming columns but then using [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) here and forwardfilling (`ffill`) over `axis=1`:

```
pd.concat([df1.rename(columns={'Annual Counts':'CanESM2'}), df2], 
           ignore_index=True, 
           sort=False).ffill(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     Year  CanESM2  GFDL-ESM2M  HadGEM2-ES365  IPSL-CM5A-MR  NorESM1-M
0  1979.0  45345.0     45345.0        45345.0       45345.0    45345.0
1  1980.0  15381.0     15381.0        15381.0       15381.0    15381.0
2  1981.0  32171.0     32171.0        32171.0       32171.0    32171.0
3  1982.0  30288.0     30288.0        30288.0       30288.0    30288.0
4  1983.0  50573.0     50573.0        50573.0       50573.0    50573.0
5  1984.0  10645.0     48143.0        57366.0       26979.0    37603.0
6  1985.0  15918.0     17178.0        34617.0       21304.0    31956.0
7  1986.0  51790.0     44111.0        50017.0       29233.0    61203.0
8  1987.0  34039.0     14504.0        23136.0       35848.0    34688.0
9  1988.0  68641.0     67681.0        24322.0       39591.0    34553.0
```